# Magento: CMS block title not changing in multi language

Tags: magento, content-management-system, block

I have (for ex:) the footer box (cms block) like this:

Title: Customer service

*Customer service
*Orders and returns
*Shipping and delivery
*Sitemap

With the Title Customer service. I have made for each language a cms with the same identifier, but different "Title". Still it gets the title for the main language, when changing language it ramains the same (only the title).

Could anyone help me?

Thank you,

Frank

Comment: Are you referring to CMS Page of Magento ?

Comment: CMS > Static Blocks. For example: Footer links. The title remains the same when changing the site language.

Comment: could you post some screenshot?

Comment: The title field of static block is just a reference. It will not be displayed anywhere. I guess you might have placed the static block in some other Magento CMS (CMS->Page) Page.You might need to change the title there.

Comment: "Block title" it is showing up, like the image (the title is highlighted): http://s28.postimg.org/5gvcsvjkd/customer.jpg  But i need it in english. If i change the block title name in the main language it will be changed, but still only one "form" of this. I need one for each language

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to display the static block in the footer.

Comment: I don't have access to ftp, yet. It's like this: http://demo.pagayo.com/pagayotheme001 - bottom. I don't know if this helps you.

Comment: Sorry it is difficult to suggest a solution without knowing how you have inserted the static block inside the footer.

Comment: Could you tell where i can find the code for it (beginner)? Thanks in advance

Comment: @rohit-s I think this is it: `<block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
            </block>`

Comment: You can use Template path hints functionality of magento to locate the exact file.Check out this link http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/12659-How-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-in-magento for more info

Comment: This is the code for the box: `<div class="footer2-container">
   <div class="footer2">
    <div class="box1">
           <div class="headline"><?php echo $footerbox1->getTitle(); ?></div>
           <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pt001-footer-box1')->toHtml() ?>
          </div>` Seems that i have there getTitle().

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet. That "string" ->getTitle() - i need to be different in each language. @RohitS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code to instantiate the object $footerbox1

```
    <?php $footerbox1=Mage::getModel('cms/block')
                        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                        ->load("pt001-footer-box1"); ?>
```